# How to show second spinner data based on first spinner. Json is coming from url?

Tags: android, arrays, json, spinner

Till now I am getting JSON and putting them in 3 different spinners. But the problem is that how to make 2nd spinner data based on the 1st spinner and 3rd spinner data based on the 2nd spinner.

```
       This is my code for JSON.

            try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                Results worldpop = new Results();

                worldpop.setSyllabus(jsonobject.optString("syllabus"));
                worldpop.setGrade(jsonobject.optString("grade"));
                worldpop.setSubject(jsonobject.optString("subject"));
                //worldpop.setFlag(jsonobject.optString("flag"));
                world.add(worldpop);


                worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("syllabus"));
                worldlist2.add(jsonobject.optString("grade"));
                worldlist3.add(jsonobject.optString("subject"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml

        final Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.syllabus);
        Spinner mySpinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.grade);
        Spinner mySpinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.subject);

        // Spinner adapter


        LinkedHashSet<String> listToSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(worldlist);

        //Creating Arraylist without duplicate values
        final List<String> worldlistnew = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet);




     mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        worldlistnew));

        listToSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(worldlist2);

        //Creating Arraylist without duplicate values
        final List<String> worldlistnew2 = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet);



        mySpinner2
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        worldlistnew2));

        listToSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(worldlist3);

        //Creating Arraylist without duplicate values
        final List<String> worldlistnew3 = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet);
        mySpinner3
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        worldlistnew3));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                               View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
```

something to be done here.

```
                      //  Results population = (Results)                   mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(position);
                      //  worldlistnew2.setText("" + population.getGrade());
                       // worldlistnew3.setText("" + population.getSubject());


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Comment: You can either filter your JSON result based on your first selection or you can make a network call to fetch data from server based on the selection in first spinner

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. In this example depending on first spinner second spinner values gets changes. and it will also change the text in the actitivty, which ever value you are selecting in second spinner. If this helps you please vote.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Courses extends Activity {




Spinner s1,s2;
TextView seats_t,t2,hod_det;
ImageView im1;
String s;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.courses);



    s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.grad);
    s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.streams);
    seats_t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.about1);
    t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hodname1);
    hod_det=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hoddetails);
    im1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hodimage);
    t2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>H.O.D</b>"));

    final ArrayList<String> s1_options = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> s2_options = new ArrayList<String>();

    s1_options.add("Under Graduate");
    s1_options.add("Post Graduate");


    ArrayAdapter<String> friendAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            s1_options);
    s1.setAdapter(friendAdapter);

    ArrayAdapter<String> subFriendAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            s2_options);
    s2.setAdapter(subFriendAdapter);

    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String friendName = s1_options.get(position).toString();
            resetFriend(friendName);
      //                subFriend.setAdapter(null);

        }

        private void resetFriend(String friendName) {
            s2_options.removeAll(s2_options);
            if (friendName.equals("Under Graduate")) {
                s2_options.add("B.Tech(C.S.E)");
                s2_options.add("B.Tech(E.C.E)");
                s2_options.add("B.Tech(E.E.E)");
                s2_options.add("B.Tech(I.T)");

            } else if (friendName.equals("Post Graduate")) {
                s2_options.add("M.B.A");
                s2_options.add("M.C.A");
                s2_options.add("M.Tech(C.N)");
                s2_options.add("M.Tech(C.S)");
                s2_options.add("M.Tech(C.S.E)");
                s2_options.add("M.Tech(V.L.S.I)");
                s2_options.add("M.Tech(D.S.C.E)");
            } 
            ArrayAdapter<String> subFriendAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s2_options);
            s2.setAdapter(subFriendAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

    });

    s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {


             s=((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();

            if(s.equals("B.Tech(C.S.E)"))
            {

                seats_t.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Computer Science Engineering:</b> - 180 seats"));



            }

            if(s.equals("B.Tech(E.C.E)"))
            {

                seats_t.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Electronics and Communication Engineering:</b> - 180 seats"));



            }
            if(s.equals("B.Tech(E.E.E)"))
            {   

                seats_t.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Electrical and Electronics Engineering:</b> - 60 seats"));



            }

            if(s.equals("M.Tech(D.S.C.E)"))
            {   
                seats_t.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>M.Tech. ( D.S.C.E.):</b> - 24(2nd shift seats"));

            }


        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}


  }
```

Comment: Sorry dude my data is coming from URL and it is very huge (1000 at least) so I can"t check one by one.Is there any easy way?

Comment: whole data coming bu only one URL

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener`

and set listener to spinner by using code below

```
 spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

 spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and also in `onItemSelected`  Where you can populate data in to second spinner based on value selected on first spinner using

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
        if (spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner1) {

 // here you can populate  data in to second spinner
}
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

First You specify json data formate.
I work on one type of json data formate like.

```
{
  "City": [
    {
      "name": "Ahmedabad",
      "City_area1" : "Ghatlodia",
      "City_area2" : "Chandlodia",
      "City_area3" : "Other"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hydarabad",
      "City_area1" : "IIT",
      "City_area2" : "Faridabad",
      "City_area3" : "Other"
    },
    {
      "name": "Noida",
      "City_area1" : "Sector-50",
      "City_area2" : "Sector-41",
      "City_area3" : "Other"
    }
  ]
}
```

city.java

```
public class city {
    private String city;
    private String Area1;
    private String Area2;
    private String Area3;

    public String getArea1() {
        return Area1;
    }

    public void setArea1(String area1) {
        Area1 = area1;
    }

    public String getArea2() {
        return Area2;
    }

    public void setArea2(String area2) {
        Area2 = area2;
    }

    public String getArea3() {
        return Area3;
    }

    public void setArea3(String area3) {
        Area3 = area3;
    }

    public city(String area1, String area2, String area3, String city) {

        Area1 = area1;
        Area2 = area2;
        Area3 = area3;
        this.city = city;
    }



    public city() {

    }

    public String getCity() {

        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner selectcityspinner;
    ArrayList<String> citylist;
    ArrayList<city> cityandarealist;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        selectcityspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selectcityspin);
        citylist = new ArrayList<>();
        new cityAsynTask().execute("Jason data url");//put your url over here
    }
    public class cityAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
    {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            cityandarealist = new ArrayList<city>();

            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    JSONObject jobjcity = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jobjcity.getJSONArray("City");
                    for (int i = 0;i < jarray.length();i++){
                        city city = new city();
                        JSONObject jrealobject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        city.setCity(jrealobject.getString("name"));
                        city.setArea1(jrealobject.getString("City_area1"));
                        city.setArea2(jrealobject.getString("City_area2"));
                        city.setArea3(jrealobject.getString("City_area3"));
                        cityandarealist.add(city);
                        citylist.add(jrealobject.getString("name"));

                    }
                    return true;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            if(aBoolean == false){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"data isnot recieved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else  {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,citylist);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                selectcityspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                selectcityspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        String Country = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                        Spinner selectareaspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectareaspin);
                        List<String> AreaList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        AreaList.add(cityandarealist.get(position).getArea1());
                        AreaList.add(cityandarealist.get(position).getArea2());
                        AreaList.add(cityandarealist.get(position).getArea3());
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, AreaList);
                        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        selectareaspinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Main_axtivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Select_City"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/Country"/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/selectcityspin"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Country"
    ></Spinner>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/selectareaspin"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/selectcityspin"
    ></Spinner>
```

if you satisfy than upvote otherwise comment your json data format/

Answer (score 0):

hi shewtabh singh first u need to store json data into hashmap like this see below after type cast your first spinner apply set on itemselected listener to the spinner reference than do like this

private HashMap hmBillDispute = new HashMap();

```
spn_DisputeBill.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            strCustomerCode = hmBillDispute.get(spn_DisputeBill.getSelectedItem().toString());
            String strFromCustomerName = spn_DisputeBill.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (!strFromCustomerName.equalsIgnoreCase("Customer Name")) {

                doInBackground(GET_DISPUTE_BILL_HISTORY_LIST);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

now you will get the data based on first spinner item selection

Comment: ThankYou @Sanjay I got the answer by myself it is something same like your answer.

Comment: if this answer is relevant to yous query than vote it...@Shwetabh Singh

Answer (score 0):

I know, am late but this code is running in my project just take a look, may be this is for upcoming people. on first spinner click you have to add Json data to second spinner, same you will do for third spinner.

```
BetterSpinner spinnerOne, spinnerTwo;
ArrayAdapter<String> taxTypeDisAdaptor;
String taxTypeDisArray[] = {"Addition", "Discount", "Tax"};

private void setSipnnerAdaptors() {

    taxTypeDisAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, taxTypeDisArray);
    spinnerOne.setAdapter(taxTypeDisAdaptor);
    spinnerOne.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            gSttaxTypeDis = taxTypeDisArray[position];

            switch (gSttaxTypeDis) {
                case "Addition":
                    ledgertype_id = "4";
                    getLedgerData();
                    break;
                case "Tax":
                    ledgertype_id = "2";
                    getLedgerData();
                    break;
                case "Discount":
                    ledgertype_id = "3";
                    getLedgerData();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    spinnerTwo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SetterAndGetter swt = (SetterAndGetter) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            gSTax_Ledgerid = String.valueOf((Integer) swt.tag);

        }
    });
}

public void getLedgerData() {

    String urls = "Json url " + ledgertype_id + "";
    String keyIds = "key";
    String values = "value";
    itemListLedger = CommonSpinnerDAta.addSpinnerdata(urls, keyIds, values);

    ArrayAdapter<SetterAndGetter> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SetterAndGetter>(mContext, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, itemListLedger);
    spinnerTwo.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```